# lxd forkstart: the famous error

Tags: kernel, lxc, lxd

I just started diving into the cloud computing, trying to hypervisor my ubuntu server. I started with LXD but it raises few issues at early stage.

Whenever I want to create a container lxd send this message:

```
 error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart "name of my container" "container path/lxc.conf"': err='exit status 1'
```

I was using the ubuntu server with kernel 4.0.18 (the latest one) and then after spending sometimes (hours) I found that most of those using LXD have faced the same issue and they solved by downgrading the kernel. 
I did that and downgraded my kernel to -4.0.0, but with no luck, I still have the same message error.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Will appreciate your help

Comment: Typo, I mean kernel 4.2.0-18-generic

Comment: You can [edit] your questions to fix typos. :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @kos? Aren't you able to understand my question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a .log file in the directory mentioned in the error message.

Alternatively this should pull it out too:

```
lxc info NAME --show-log
```

In the past, the most frequent source of this error was a system where liblxc1 was out of date, so you may want to triple check that everything's up to date and also mention what version of LXD you're running.

As far as I'm aware, the current Ubuntu 15.10 kernel (4.2) works fine with LXD, so you may want to get back to the latest and we can then debug from there.